# Having Issue on Creating and Quering MySQL Temporary Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, mysqli

I am having issue on getting json Data from a Temporary table. As you can see I tried to generate a Temporary Table `charts_econo` at `$query` and in second query `$query2` I tried to parse the table into JSON but I am getting nothing.

Here is my php file

```
<?PHP
include 'conconfig.php';
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$collm = $_POST['column'];
$query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `charts_econo` (
          `econo_sum_projects` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
          `econo_sum_powerline` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
          `econo_sum_roads` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
          `econo_sum_cost` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL
          ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AS(SELECT COUNT(`project`),
                                                   SUM(`powerline_length`),
                                                   SUM(`road_length`),
                                                   SUM(`cost_per_year`)
                                                   FROM `econo` WHERE c_1000=1;";
$con->query($query);
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `charts_econo`" ;
$results = $con->query($query2);
if($results) {
  while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
     $json=json_encode($row);
  }
}
$con->close();
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Is error reporting on and up?

Comment: Hi Explosion Pills, no I am not getiin any error! it is just an empty white page. Is there any way to debug the page?

Comment: Sidenote: I take it that you have an existing table called `econo`?

Comment: Also, you seem to be closing your DB connection before your echo, whether that makes a difference or not, am not 100% sure.

Comment: @Fred, yes I have an existing table called econo and need to load data to Temporary table from there

Comment: What's the purpose of the temporary table?  Why not just loop through the results of the select query?

Comment: Not sure if JSON is capable of reading a temp table from a previous statement (each statement is it's own session, temp tables don't cross).  2 solutions...why not just select from the temp table in the first query (create statement then select in same query), or even skip the temp table and select directly from the select statement that populates it.  2nd solution...I beleive you can make this table a global temp table (but I'm unsure if MySQL supports that)

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9597989/ I think you need to add something to `echo $json;` what do you get when you do `var_dump($json);` or `var_dump($results);`?

Comment: @MonaCoder: Your parent `as (select ...` query needs a closing parenthesis `)`. It is missing. Otherwise remove the opening parenthesis `(` after `AS`.